# re-assigning value based on other variables within group in r

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame with 4 columns -- ID, days, pod, and value.

```
df <- data.frame(ID = rep(1:3, each = 4),
                 days = c(1, 7, 12, 7, 10, 10, 1, 7, 14, 7, 7, 20),
                 pod = factor(c("t1", "t2", "t3", "t2", "t2", "t2", "t1", "t2", "t3", "t2", "t2", "t3")),
                 value = rnorm(12, mean = 0, sd = 1))
```

There are 4 values for each ID. For each pod time I'd like to select the value where the day is closest to the following convention:

pod t1 -- day 1;
pod t2 -- day 7;
pod t3 -- day 14

Ideally, I'd like to end up with the following data frame:

```
   ID days pod       value
1   1    1  t1 -0.66080611
2   1    7  t2 -1.06817352
3   1   12  t3 -0.50972605
4   1    7  t2          NA
5   2   10  t2          NA
6   2   10  t2          NA
7   2    1  t1  0.32221657
8   2    7  t2  0.96108912
9   3   14  t3 -0.03138917
10  3    7  t2  0.36659820
11  3    7  t2          NA
12  3   20  t3          NA
```

Basically, I'd like to replace the value with NA if it's not the closest to the day within the ID and pod group. If the days and time are equal within a group, then I'd just like to select the first.

Comment: Should include a seed with your example!

Comment: Yes, agreed. I apologize for that. The actual values 'value' variable in my example don't really affect what I'm looking to do. Again, sorry about not including a seed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find it problematic that you want to replace the values with same day depending on the order, which is easily messed up. Is there anything more ... reliable... which could define which values you omit? 
The following code comes close to what you want, but it's currently 'only' replacing the repetitive 'pods' with the value of the first one:

```
    set.seed(1)
dat <- data.frame(ID = rep(1:3, each = 4),
                 days = c(1, 7, 12, 7, 10, 10, 1, 7, 14, 7, 7, 20),
                 pod = factor(c("t1", "t2", "t3", "t2", "t2", "t2", "t1", "t2", "t3", "t2", "t2", "t3")),
                 value = rnorm(12, mean = 0, sd = 1))

dat %>% mutate(helper = case_when(pod == 't1' ~ days-1,
                                  pod == 't2' ~ days-7,
                                  pod == 't3' ~ days-14)) %>%
  group_by(ID, pod) %>% mutate(min = ifelse(helper == min(helper), 
                                            first(value), NA ))

# A tibble: 12 x 6
# Groups:   ID, pod [7]
      ID  days pod    value helper     min
   <int> <dbl> <fct>  <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>
 1     1  1.00 t1    -0.626   0    - 0.626
 2     1  7.00 t2     0.184   0      0.184
 3     1 12.0  t3    -0.836  -2.00 - 0.836
 4     1  7.00 t2     1.60    0      0.184
 5     2 10.0  t2     0.330   3.00  NA    
 6     2 10.0  t2    -0.820   3.00  NA    
 7     2  1.00 t1     0.487   0      0.487
 8     2  7.00 t2     0.738   0      0.330
 9     3 14.0  t3     0.576   0      0.576
10     3  7.00 t2    -0.305   0    - 0.305
11     3  7.00 t2     1.51    0    - 0.305
12     3 20.0  t3     0.390   6.00  NA
```

Now added another conditional. This is some ifelse nesting and maybe not most elegant, but it gives what you want, I hope:)

```
dat %>% mutate(helper = case_when(pod == 't1' ~ days-1,
                                  pod == 't2' ~ days-7,
                                  pod == 't3' ~ days-14)) %>%
  group_by(ID, pod) %>% mutate(min = ifelse(helper == min(helper), 
                                            ifelse(value == first(value), value, NA ), NA))


# A tibble: 12 x 6
# Groups:   ID, pod [7]
      ID  days pod    value helper     min
   <int> <dbl> <fct>  <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>
 1     1  1.00 t1    -0.626   0    - 0.626
 2     1  7.00 t2     0.184   0      0.184
 3     1 12.0  t3    -0.836  -2.00 - 0.836
 4     1  7.00 t2     1.60    0     NA    
 5     2 10.0  t2     0.330   3.00  NA    
 6     2 10.0  t2    -0.820   3.00  NA    
 7     2  1.00 t1     0.487   0      0.487
 8     2  7.00 t2     0.738   0     NA    
 9     3 14.0  t3     0.576   0      0.576
10     3  7.00 t2    -0.305   0    - 0.305
11     3  7.00 t2     1.51    0     NA    
12     3 20.0  t3     0.390   6.00  NA
```

Comment: This works for me! Thank you. You're right -- it's a bit clunky when the days are equal. That hasn't come up in my actual data, I just suspect it could, so I wanted to be inclusive.